# How to check if a file is a text file?

Tags: file-type, raku

Does Perl6 have something like the Perl5 [-T file test](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) to tell if a file is a text file?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's nothing built in, however there is a module [Data::TextOrBinary](https://github.com/jnthn/p6-data-textorbinary) that does that.

```
use Data::TextOrBinary;
say is-text('/bin/bash'.IO);                            # False
say is-text('/usr/share/dict/words'.IO);                # True
```

Answer (score 11):

That's a heuristic that [has not been translated to Perl 6](https://docs.perl6.org/type/IO::Path#File_test_operators). You can simply read it in UTF8 (or ASCII) to do the same:

```
given slurp("read-utf8.p6", enc => 'utf8') -> $f {
    say "UTF8";
}
```

(substitute read-utf8.p6 by the name of the file you want to check)

Comment: actually, if the file isn't valid utf8, this will throw an exception. also, it won't understand utf16, for example

Comment: @timotimo right, but the original one just checked for ASCII or UTF8. A battery of encodings should have to be checked, but the general idea would be the same.

Comment: @jjmerelo Your comment disagrees with the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899206/how-does-perl-know-a-file-is-binary

Answer (score 5):

we can make use of the File::Type with the following code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Type;

my $file      = '/path/to/file.ext';
my $ft        = File::Type->new();
my $file_type = $ft->mime_type($file);

if ( $file_type eq 'application/octet-stream' ) {
    # possibly a text file
}
elsif ( $file_type eq 'application/zip' ) {
    # file is a zip archive
}
```

Source: https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Type

Comment: This is a perl5 module, but question is about a perl6 solution.

Comment: This could be edited to `use File::Type:from<Perl5>` and `$ft.mime_type($file)` to be Perl6 code.